# Ant getting stuck at [get] call in jmeter install behind authenticating proxy

Tags: java, ant, proxy, installation, linux-mint

I am trying to install JMeter in Linux Mint. I am behind an authenticating proxy, and I am invoking ant as `ant -autoproxy download_jars`. This gives me following output, and then gets stuck.

```
download_jars:

_process_all_jars:

_check_exists:

_check_jarfile:
     [echo] Checking bsf-2.4.0.jar
     [echo] Deleting bsf-*.jar (excluding bsf-2.4.0.jar)

_get_jarfile:
     [echo] Fetching: lib/bsf-2.4.0.jar
      [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/bsf/bsf/2.4.0/bsf-2.4.0.jar
      [get] To: /home/xxx/xxx/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.10/build/bsf-2.4.0.jar
```

It never actually gets the file, nor it reports any error. System monitor shows negligible network activity (~4kB/sec). Even after waiting for long, the process does not finish.

How do I proceed in such a case to install ant from source? Downloading all JARs by hand is impractical.

update: The call fails with following exception:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/xxx/xxx/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.10/build.xml:2944: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/xxx/xxx/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.10/build.xml:2870: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/xxx/xxx/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.10/build.xml:2764: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/xxx/xxx/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.10/build.xml:2807: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/xxx/xxx/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.10/build.xml:2837: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:111)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:448)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:240)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:338)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:935)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:660)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.get(Get.java:579)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.run(Get.java:569)

Total time: 15 minutes 2 seconds
```